When I close my tkinter window I get an error: return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get') -> tkinter.TclError invalid command name ".!frame4. !entry"
When I close my tkinter window, I am receiving this error on my command line.
The only other issue with my program is that when I enter text using my "enter_button" - I have to hit enter twice or click the button twice for the text to be displayed. Im not sure if they are related.
Edit: I am calling root.mainloop() in my main.py file, which also is where I'm handling my game state variable. Edit2: added root.mainloop() to my code block for clarity that it is included in my program.
These are the widgets that the error is referring to:

#game input frame    
entry_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
entry_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = "ew", padx = (15,5))

entry_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 25)
entry_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 2)

text_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame)
text_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
text_entry.focus()

text_entry.bind("<Return>", add_to_game_out)

enter_button = ttk.Button(entry_frame, text = "Enter", command = add_to_game_out)
enter_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

And this is the entirety of my graphics.py file in this program:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.title("Start Game")

root.configure(background = "#212121")

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 2)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 5)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 5)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 5)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight = 2)

#button frame

button_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

button_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
button_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
button_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
button_frame.rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
button_frame.rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)
button_frame.rowconfigure(4, weight = 1)

help_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text = "Help")
help_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

inventory_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text = "Inventory")
inventory_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

spells_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text = "Spells")
spells_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

styles_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text = "Styles")
styles_button.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

#status frame
status_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
status_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 2, 
                  sticky = "nsew", padx = 5, pady = (5,15))

label = ttk.Label(status_frame, background = "#373737", 
                  text = "Status box", anchor = "n")
label.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

#game output frame
text_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
text_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

game_text = tk.Text(text_frame, background = "#212121", 
                            wrap = "word"
)                  
game_text.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

#output tags
game_text.tag_configure("title", background = "#212121", 
                        font=("Times New Roman", 12, "bold"), 
                        foreground = "#9B61AB")
game_text.tag_configure("user", background = "#212121", 
                        font=("Times New Roman", 11), 
                        foreground = "#D7D7D7")
game_text.tag_configure("output", background = "#212121",
                        font=("Times New Roman", 12, "bold"),
                        foreground = "#759EE0")

#output to text box with optional text arguments
def game_out(text, tags = "user"):
    game_text.configure(state = "normal")
    game_text.insert(tk.END, f"{text}\n", tags)
    game_text.configure(state = "disabled")
    game_text.see(tk.END)

#display content and progress game using gamestate()
def add_to_game_out(event=None):
    from main import gamestate, gstate
    if text_entry.get():
        text = text_entry.get()
        text_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        # print(f"State: {gstate}")
        return gamestate(text)

#title/credits printed upon execution
with open("text_files/narrative.txt") as start:
    start = start.readlines()
    count = 0
    beginning = "***TitleStart***"
    end = "***TitleEnd***"
    section = []
    for line in start:
        if beginning in line:
            section.append(count)
        if end in line:
            section.append(count)
        count += 1
    for line in range(section[0]+1, section[1]):
        game_out(start[line], "title")

#game input frame    
entry_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
entry_frame.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = "ew", padx = (15,5))

entry_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 25)
entry_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 2)

text_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame)
text_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
text_entry.focus()

text_entry.bind("<Return>", add_to_game_out)

enter_button = ttk.Button(entry_frame, text = "Enter", command = add_to_game_out)
enter_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

#close window and destroy widgets
def close_window():
    enter_button.destroy()
    text_entry.destroy()
    entry_frame.destroy()
    root.destroy()


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_window)

#not actually in my graphics.py, root.mainloop() is in my main.py file
root.mainloop()

I have tried adding a function to close and destroy widgets because I was reading some other questions and answers where that was the solution, but I am still receiving the error even after implementing:
#close window and destroy widgets
def close_window():
    enter_button.destroy()
    text_entry.destroy()
    entry_frame.destroy()
    root.destroy()


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_window)

Example of narrative.txt contents:
***TitleStart***
===========<-Welcome to StartGame->============
----------Type and Enter "Play" to start the game-----------
--------------Click Help Button for information--------------

**************************************************************
***TitleEnd***


FWIW: You shouldn't need to set up a protocol handler to destroy widgets explicitly; all children of the root will be destroyed when it is (i.e., when the window is closed)

Also, root.mainloop is never called, and it would be useful to include an example of the narrative.txt file's content.

Thank you @JRiggles, I edited my post to clarify that root.mainloop() is in my main.py file, and I included a snippet of what is in my narrative.txt file.

Where is the root.mainloop()?

root.mainloop() is in my main.py file, I also added it to my code block here for clarity that it is in my program. Apologies for the confusion about root.mainloop().

Don't add solved in question.  Either add an answer and accept it,  or delete the question.

@acw1668 ok, I added an answer. Thank you for the suggestion.

As I mentioned in my edits, I was running root.mainloop() in my main.py file, which is not where my tkinter code is written. After adding if __name__ == "__main__": to my main.py file, I no longer get the error in my title printed to my CLI, and my enter button works as expected.
def main():
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I'm not totally sure why this solved both problems I was having.
